# Spring Boot - MongoDB - Inheritance

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mongodb

I'm running into something odd with inheritance and mongodbrepositories.

I have the following:

`

```
@Document
public class Base {
    public String fieldA;
}
```

```
public class Derived extends Base {
    public String fieldB;
}
```

```
public interface DerivedRepository extends MongoRepository<Base, String> {
    List<Derived> findByFieldA(String fieldA);
}
```

`

When inserting i get

> Inserting DBObject containing fields: [_class, _id, fieldA, fieldB ]
>   in collection: base

When i do findByFieldA('some value') on the repository i get the following:

> find using query: { "fieldA" : "some value" } fields: null for class:
>   class Derived in collection: derived

Any idea what is going on here? And how can I fix this, either by saving it to the proper derived collection or by querying from the base collection.

Regards,

Answer (score 14, accepted):

First, I would make `Derived` class as document since the parent is going to be shared among many implementations.

```
public class Base {
    public String fieldA;
}

@Document
public class Derived extends Base {
    public String fieldB;

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "{fieldA: " + getFieldA() + ", fieldB: " + fieldB + "}";
    }
}
```

Second, change the repository specification with the type of document (class marked as @Document) as:

```
public interface DerivedRepository extends MongoRepository<Derived, String> {
    List<Derived> findByFieldA(String fieldA);
    List<Derived> findByFieldB(String fieldB);
}
```

I added extra method `findByFieldB(String fieldB)` to explain more.

With these changes, you should be able to query either with `fieldA` or `fieldB` as below:

```
public class SpringBootMongoApplication {
    @Autowired
    private DerivedRepository derivedRepository;

    public void testMethod() throws Exception {
        Derived derived1 = new Derived();
        derived1.setFieldB("fieldB1");
        derived1.setFieldA("fieldA1");

        Derived derived2 = new Derived();
        derived2.setFieldB("fieldB2");
        derived2.setFieldA("fieldA2");
        this.derivedRepository.save(Arrays.asList(derived1, derived2));

        List<Derived> deriveds = this.derivedRepository.findByFieldA("fieldA1");
        System.out.println(deriveds);

        List<Derived> deriveds1 = this.derivedRepository.findByFieldB("fieldB2");
        System.out.println(deriveds1);
    }
}
```

The output should be:

```
[{fieldA: fieldA1, fieldB: fieldB1}]
[{fieldA: fieldA2, fieldB: fieldB2}]
```

You can also verify the object persisted and their types with mongo query as below:
[image]

I have created an Spring Boot sample app which you can find in [Github](https://github.com/YogenRaii/spring-examples/tree/master/spring-boot-mongo).